# Maven - a set-up query

Tags: maven, maven-3

Given a group of developers, each one has the following requirements on the respective (local)Windows machines:

1. Through IDEs like Eclipse, STS etc., run Spring, Hibernate etc. projects
2. Quickly build, deploy , run, change if required, rebuild and redeploy(everything, preferably via IDEs) the projects available on Github

There are following constraints/objectives :

1. The individual developer machines have restricted or no Internet access
2. The developers must take the required jars from a single location which will store jars required across the team
3. Whenever required, a developer must be able to pull updated jars from the central location onto his local environment and continue to run the projects seamlessly
4. Within the IDE, build a Github project and run it (locally)

Attached is the image to give a clear idea of the work environment which I'm envisaging!

I have started reading Maven but quite overwhelmed - how should I proceed?

[image: Desired set-up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Sander Verhagen in another answer, what you should do is to use a repository proxy.  Nexus and Artifactory is the most famous one.  Here I will describe briefly steps you need to do for what you are looking for:

1. Set up Nexus in machine M
2. In Nexus, setup a proxy repository to Central (this should be available out of box), and other repositories that you want your developer to access.  You may need to add http proxy setting when you are configuring the Repo Proxy.
3. (Optional, but recommended) setup a repository group which includes all the public repository proxies. Assuming URL of this proxy group is `http://M/nexus/groups/public`
4. In developer's machine, update ~/.m2/settings.xml, set `http://M/nexus/groups/public` as the mirror of central.  If you created other internal hosted repositories in Nexus, you may add them in settings.xml as well.

That's all.  You can use Maven as normal.  Dependencies will now be fetched from Nexus in M.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an internal Maven repository. There is such applications as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) (those are probably the close numbers 1 and 2 in the business, just my opinion). You can set it up to use your proxy server.

It will be able to serve as a proxy for your Maven clients, and keep a copy of the artifacts that are downloaded. They will even allow you control over what kind of artifacts your developers pull in (although they may not always appreciate that).

It will also be able to store and serve your own artifacts that your developers can [`deploy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) ([`release`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)) to it.

Maven is great at dependency management, and that is what most organizations start using it for. But as your process matures, there is also the opportunity for version/release management using Maven. Developers will build `SNAPSHOT` versions for themselves, or share these with the team through the repository. When they [`release`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) their artifacts, they make a final version of the artifact available in the repository.

Maven has great support for your IDEs, myself I use Eclipse a lot, which has [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) to work with Maven.

Apache itself on '[Why do I need a Repository Manager?](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)'

---

New tools require adaptation, sometimes culture shifts. And in the case of Maven, where many organizations come from scripted builds, it may require a paradigm shift. It sounds a bit as if you're at risk of being overwhelmed some more in the future. I think it will be worth your effort, but you may want to get some experienced help to get you on track.

---

More of a personal note: done with those proxy servers, alright!

Comment: Can you list the baby-steps(spoon-fed,rather) as to how I must proceed, given I have machine M(master with Internet connection where the master repo. must rest) and developer machines d1, d2? Do I have to use Archive, Nexus etc. to implement my design?

Comment: I think the information given by @Sander is already more than enough for you to start.  It is simply not reasonable to ask for spoon-feeding for an adult who should have the ability to solve the problem.  Anyway, I will be giving some steps for you to follow in another answer.  However, you should do your work in doing study and googling to find out the actual steps to use

Comment: Actually, I was not sure whether Nexus etc. are a mandate to achieve the design, hence, asked for the detailed steps.

Comment: In brief, yes, Nexus or other repo proxy is required for such design.  Basically how Maven work in resolving dependencies is: it will first check if your local repo has such artifact, if not, it will download from remote repo to local repo.  Then artifacts in local repo is used.  Therefore you should provide a way to provide a remote repo for your developers to fetch artifact from if you want it to be centralized and controlled.  Hence, service like Nexus/Artifactory is required.