# mark maven artifacts for later re-packaging the exact output

Tags: maven

I'm looking for a way to mark the artifacts used by maven to re-package wars.

Since some of the dependencies I use, depend on range of versions, the artifacts may change over time, and I want the ability to re-release a specific version of my web application (for example, when hotfix is needed).

After some research, I found that I can use 
mvn  dependency:go-offline -Dmaven.repo.local=/path

to save all dependencies in /path, and later

mvn  -o -Dmaven.repo.local=/path

to use the same artifacts.

This is a fair solution, but will require large amount of storage (or maintaining a version control repository of that storage).

I'm looking for a solution which is more elegant, that uses only the artifact names and versions, instead of actual files. I saw that there's dependency:list and dependency:tree mojos which shows the dependencies used, but is there a way to tell maven to use this list as an input to avoid updating artifacts?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you really just looking for a [company-internal Maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985055/maven-a-set-up-query/18995218#18995218)? And yes, if you desire a whole slew of versions of the same artifact, you're paying the price of storage (luckily not too bad these days).

Comment: I'm already using internal maven repository, but I don't understand how it can help me, since it is also updated over time.

Comment: What do you mean by updated? Old artifacts will still be there, unless you clean them up specifically? Old artifacts should have distinct version numbers. Also, not unimportant, you should resolve your ranges when releasing, because you don't want to re-release the same code with different dependencies...

Comment: what do you mean 'you should resolve your ranges when releasing'? That might be the answer to my problem.

Comment: Used ranges a while. It seemed ideal on paper, but it worked against us: some tools had a hard time calculating their way through all possible dependency paths (without ranges the paths are much simpler). And then there was the releases that would also have ranges, thus being incompatible with newer versions of dependencies. The release plugin should be able to [resolve all ranges](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/generate-release-poms.html), but when we tried this (few years ago) it was unreliable. We got rid of ranges altogether.

Comment: How do you handle 3rd parties dependencies? My problem arose when a dependency of a 3rd party (which used range) changed.

Comment: We never used ranges for third party dependencies to begin with. When a third party releases a new version we want to retest our apps and consciously upgrade anyway. We only ever tried ranges between internal projects, since we fell that'd give us Continuous Integration. Finally we choose for CI within projects, and then consciously release and thus integrate with other projects.